# Can I get power from my Belkin Express Dock HD (Thunderbolt 2) for my MacBook Pro Retina?

Tags: dock, thunderbolt, power, lightning

I plug my MacBook Pro to my Belkin Express Dock HD via Thunderbolt, but I see that my battery is getting down. I was hopping to get power from the Dock. Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

A Thunderbolt port can provide up to **10W**. That's enough to charge a phone or a tablet but definitely not a notebook.

A Macbook (Air/Pro) needs  between 45 and 90W.

Answer (score 0):

The MBP is not a thunderbolt device; it is a laptop with its own power source, and a thunderbolt port.

If you need to replace the power adapter for your MBP, then take care to obtain the correct wattage.